# libc : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 3829 (EventThread), pid 2863 TV AP

Tags: android, android-tv, exoplayer2.x

I am seeing crash on my android TV app, I am looping a video using exoplayer endlessly(8 to 12hrs) & in between app is getting crashed with libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 3829 (EventThread), pid 2863 error.

here I am attaching the log -

```
8-13 17:18:49.337  2863  3829 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 3829 (EventThread), pid 2863 (om.wallview.app)
08-13 17:18:50.188  3849  3849 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
08-13 17:18:50.188  3849  3849 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Sony/BRAVIA_VU2/BRAVIA_VU1_2K:11/RTT7.210426.001/73-60427:user/release-keys'
08-13 17:18:50.188  3849  3849 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
08-13 17:18:50.189  3849  3849 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
08-13 17:18:50.197  3849  3849 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2022-08-13 17:18:50+0530
08-13 17:18:50.197  3849  3849 F DEBUG   : pid: 2863, tid: 3829, name: EventThread  >>> com.wallview.app <<<
08-13 17:18:50.197  3849  3849 F DEBUG   : uid: 10091
08-13 17:18:50.197  3849  3849 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
08-13 17:18:50.197  3849  3849 F DEBUG   :     r0  00000000  r1  00000ef5  r2  00000006  r3  b7f9edd8
08-13 17:18:50.197  3849  3849 F DEBUG   :     r4  b7f9edec  r5  b7f9edd0  r6  00000b2f  r7  0000016b
08-13 17:18:50.197  3849  3849 F DEBUG   :     r8  b7f9edd8  r9  b7f9ede8  r10 b7f9ee08  r11 b7f9edf8
08-13 17:18:50.197  3849  3849 F DEBUG   :     ip  00000ef5  sp  b7f9eda8  lr  b3c95a41  pc  b3c95a54
08-13 17:18:50.252  3849  3849 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
08-13 17:18:50.252  3849  3849 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 00038a54  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (abort+172) (BuildId: 2d3223c28a2147a5dbd4b9b709eabc6b)
08-13 17:18:50.252  3849  3849 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 0002e70f  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (scudo::die()+2) (BuildId: 2d3223c28a2147a5dbd4b9b709eabc6b)
08-13 17:18:50.253  3849  3849 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 0002e1bb  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (scudo::dieOnMapUnmapError(bool)+30) (BuildId: 2d3223c28a2147a5dbd4b9b709eabc6b)
08-13 17:18:50.253  3849  3849 F DEBUG   :       #03 pc 0002e797  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (scudo::map(void*, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long, scudo::MapPlatformData*)+132) (BuildId: 2d3223c28a2147a5dbd4b9b709eabc6b)
08-13 17:18:50.253  3849  3849 F DEBUG   :       #04 pc 00031cc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (scudo::PackedCounterArray::PackedCounterArray(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long)+184) (BuildId: 2d3223c28a2147a5dbd4b9b709eabc6b)
08-13 17:18:50.255  3849  3849 F DEBUG   :       #05 pc 00031795  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (void scudo::releaseFreeMemoryToOS<scudo::SizeClassAllocatorLocalCache<scudo::SizeClassAllocator32<scudo::TableSizeClassMap<scudo::AndroidSizeClassConfig>, 18ul, 1000, 1000> >::TransferBatch, scudo::ReleaseRecorder, scudo::SizeClassAllocator32<scudo::TableSizeClassMap<scudo::AndroidSizeClassConfig>, 18ul, 1000, 1000>::releaseToOSMaybe(scudo::SizeClassAllocator32<scudo::TableSizeClassMap<scudo::AndroidSizeClassConfig>, 18ul, 1000, 1000>::SizeClassInfo*, unsigned long, bool)::'lambda'(unsigned long)>(scudo::IntrusiveList<scudo::SizeClassAllocatorLocalCache<scudo::SizeClassAllocator32<scudo::TableSizeClassMap<scudo::AndroidSizeClassConfig>, 18ul, 1000, 1000> >::TransferBatch> const&, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, scudo::ReleaseRecorder*, scudo::SizeClassAllocator32<scudo::TableSizeClassMap<scudo::AndroidSizeClassConfig>, 18ul, 1000, 1000>::releaseToOSMaybe(scudo::SizeClassAllocator32<scudo::TableSizeClassMap<scudo::AndroidSizeClassConfig>, 18ul, 1000, 1000>::SizeClassInfo*, unsigned long, bool)::'lambda'(unsigned long))+128) (BuildId: 2d3223c28a2147a5dbd4b9b709eabc6b)
08-13 17:18:50.255  3849  3849 F DEBUG   :       #06 pc 000316ed  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (scudo::SizeClassAllocator32<scudo::TableSizeClassMap<scudo::AndroidSizeClassConfig>, 18ul, 1000, 1000>::releaseToOSMaybe(scudo::SizeClassAllocator32<scudo::TableSizeClassMap<scudo::AndroidSizeClassConfig>, 18ul, 1000, 1000>::SizeClassInfo*, unsigned long, bool)+304) (BuildId: 2d3223c28a2147a5dbd4b9b709eabc6b)
08-13 17:18:50.255  3849  3849 F DEBUG   :       #07 pc 000315a7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (scudo::SizeClassAllocatorLocalCache<scudo::SizeClassAllocator32<scudo::TableSizeClassMap<scudo::AndroidSizeClassConfig>, 18ul, 1000, 1000> >::drain(scudo::SizeClassAllocatorLocalCache<scudo::SizeClassAllocator32<scudo::TableSizeClassMap<scudo::AndroidSizeClassConfig>, 18ul, 1000, 1000> >::PerClass*, unsigned long)+202) (BuildId: 2d3223c28a2147a5dbd4b9b709eabc6b)
08-13 17:18:50.255  3849  3849 F DEBUG   :       #08 pc 00031fd7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (scudo::Allocator<scudo::AndroidConfig, &(scudo_malloc_postinit)>::quarantineOrDeallocateChunk(void*, scudo::Chunk::UnpackedHeader*, unsigned long)+422) (BuildId: 2d3223c28a2147a5dbd4b9b709eabc6b)
08-13 17:18:50.255  3849  3849 F DEBUG   :       #09 pc 0002f931  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (scudo::Allocator<scudo::AndroidConfig, &(scudo_malloc_postinit)>::deallocate(void*, scudo::Chunk::Origin, unsigned long, unsigned long)+168) (BuildId: 2d3223c28a2147a5dbd4b9b709eabc6b)
08-13 17:18:50.255  3849  3849 F DEBUG   :       #10 pc 0002f87b  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (scudo_free+18) (BuildId: 2d3223c28a2147a5dbd4b9b709eabc6b)
08-13 17:18:50.255  3849  3849 F DEBUG   :       #11 pc 00463c85  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadList::Unregister(art::Thread*)+488) (BuildId: 2d4c898c2aaeb2cc489d7516236d9cc6)
08-13 17:18:50.256  3849  3849 F DEBUG   :       #12 pc 00445395  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1132) (BuildId: 2d4c898c2aaeb2cc489d7516236d9cc6)
08-13 17:18:50.256  3849  3849 F DEBUG   :       #13 pc 0008115f  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+40) (BuildId: 2d3223c28a2147a5dbd4b9b709eabc6b)
08-13 17:18:50.256  3849  3849 F DEBUG   :       #14 pc 00039f5d  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+30) (BuildId: 2d3223c28a2147a5dbd4b9b709eabc6b)
08-13 17:18:41.157   706   706 I chatty  : uid=1000 system_server identical 15 lines
08-13 17:18:51.165   706   706 V HotPlugDetectionAction: Poll_all_devices.
08-13 17:18:54.974   706   741 I BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_10 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
08-13 17:18:54.978   706   741 I DropBoxManagerService: add tag=SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
08-13 17:18:54.979   706  3855 I DropBoxManagerService: add tag=data_app_native_crash isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
08-13 17:18:54.998   706  3854 W ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity com.wallview.app/.activities.MainActivity
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: It seems that your application is killed by Android because of low memory. Have you tried looking at your app's memory footprint using Profiler? I guess there might be some leakage which causes the memory to become exhausted.

Comment: Hi @mahdi this seems to be not because of the low memory, I have run profile & also logging available memory status every 5 mins and here is the last memory status before termination -  D MainActivity: available mem: 0.3015861511230469
08-19 16:11:48.154  3788  3788 D MainActivity: total mem: 1.5
08-19 16:11:48.154  3788  3788 D MainActivity: low mem: false

Comment: If you think that is caused by exoplayer, feel free to raise an issue in their github repo https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues. You may get a quicker response there.